# How to detect that Taskbar Thumbnail Preview is being drawn when DWMWA_HAS_ICONIC_BITMAP is set

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-7

How to detect that Taskbar Thumbnail Preview is being drawn (because user is moving mouse over taskbar button) or is currently appearing on screen?

Why the code below does not make log entries when WM_DWMSENDICONICTHUMBNAIL msg should be arriving to form?

```
    procedure TStartInfoForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    begin        
      SetWindowAttribute(DWMWA_HAS_ICONIC_BITMAP);               
    end;
    function TStartInfoForm.SetWindowAttribute(dwAttr: DWORD): HRESULT;
    var
      Attr: function(hwnd: hwnd; dwAttribute: DWORD; pvAttribute: Pointer;
       cbAttribute: DWORD): HRESULT; stdcall;
     hndDLLHandle : THandle;
     EnableAttribute : DWORD;
    begin
      EnableAttribute := DWORD(true);
      try
        hndDLLHandle := loadLibrary('dwmapi.dll');
        if hndDLLHandle <> 0 then
        begin
          Attr := getProcAddress(hndDLLHandle, 'DwmSetWindowAttribute');
          if addr(Attr) <> nil then
           Result := Attr(Handle, dwAttr, @EnableAttribute, SizeOf(EnableAttribute));
        end;
      finally
        freeLibrary(hndDLLHandle);
      end;
    end;

procedure TStartInfoForm.WndProc(var Msg : TMessage);
begin    
 DebugNote(0,'wndproc '+inttohex(msg.Msg,3)+' w '+inttohex(Msg.wparam,3)+' l '+inttohex(Msg.lparam,3));
    
   case Msg.Msg of    
    WM_DWMSENDICONICTHUMBNAIL : 
   begin
    DebugNote(0,' iconiclive');
   end;
    WM_DWMSENDICONICLIVEPREVIEWBITMAP:
   begin
    DebugNote(0,' iconiclive2 ');    
   end;

      WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING:
      begin
//   MessageBeep(1);
      end                ;
      WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED:
      begin
//   MessageBeep(1);
      end
   end;
   inherited;// call this for default behaveour
 end;
```

Comment: `WM_DWMSENDICONICTHUMBNAIL` and `WM_DWMSENDICONICLIVEPREVIEWBITMAP` are not **posted** messages, so the `OnMessage` event will never see them. They are **sent** directly to the Form's `WindowProc` instead.

Comment: Excellent, are you interested in writing an answer to this question how to override WindowProc and catch these msgs?

Comment: I have this article but its so slow to figure it out .. :( https://doc.lagout.org/programmation/Delphi/Delphi/Delphi%20-%20Messages%20%28chapter%29.pdf

Comment: Note: I don't want to actually generate the new thumbnail, I just want to detect a situation when its being displayed.

Comment: Also there is no The DWMWA_HAS_ICONIC_BITMAP attribute set at the moment

Comment: C++ can use winapi spy or hook.

Comment: @Tom the `WindowProc` is a public property, just assign a new procedure to it. There are plenty of examples if you search around. But in order to get those messages, you must enable the DWMWA_HAS_ICONIC_BITMAP attribute on the window, telling the OS that you want to generate and provide your own preview bitmaps.

Comment: Hello I have added the code to this question  that enables attribute,   but unfortunately the code does not work, any ideas?

Comment: Yes: check if the function was found in the DLL **and** check the result of `DwmSetWindowAttribute()` instead of assuming both to always succeed.